# How to set cookie length time within a function

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie time length for my code. I have seen this code elsewhere:

```
var date = new Date();
 date.setTime(date.getTime() + (100 * 60));
$.cookie("cookie", "value", { expires: date });
```

but I can't work out hoe to implement this into this section of my code:

```
function storage() {
document.getElementById("array").innerHTML=document.cookie;
} 

document.getElementById("add").onclick= function storage() {  
if(!document.cookie) document.cookie = "";   
document.cookie = document.cookie +"<li>"+document.getElementById("textbox1").value+ ":"+"</li>";
document.cookie = document.cookie +"<li>" + document.getElementById("textbox2").value+ "</li>";
document.getElementById("array").innerHTML= document.cookie;
}
```

I would have thought that I could've done something like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var m = 10;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (100 * 60));
$.cookie("document.cookie", "value", { expires: date });
```

but I'm not sure what my value would be, plus I'm not sure if I've actually set a cookie name in any of this. I suspect the code I have made so far is doing its a job a in a very long, needless way but it seems to work, other than this time setting thing

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you're referencing is using a plugin:
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

It works like this:

`$.cookie("someKey", "some value to save", { expires : 7 }); //expires is time in days till cookie expires`

Comment: I would prefer it to be exchangeable between Computers, and I presume I would have to download the plugin for each computer I presume? Is there any other way avoiding plugins if this is the case?

Comment: You don't need to manually download the plugin on the computer... it's just like using jquery - you don't download jquery on the computer, you include the script tag and it loads it.

The same is with the plugin. Just include the script tag for the plugin right after the jquery script tag and it should work.

Comment: and what is the script tag for the plugin? the link seems to come up with several options so I don't know which one if the one you mean